# Why readFile of react-native-fs only read part of a text file?

Tags: react-native, readfile, react-native-fs

I was trying to read from a text file with react-native-fs readFile function, the resulting string always ended at certain chars.

I've change the contents of the text file, it still ended after 4094 chars.

```
  await RNFS.readFile(p, 'utf8')
    .then((readresult) => {
    console.log(readresult);
    res = {success: true, contents: readresult};
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('ERROR' + err.message);
    res = {success: false, errorMsg: err.message};
  })
```

Log always produces first 4094 chars.

Answer (score 3):

You could try reading the file piece by piece using [read](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readfilepath-string-length--0-position--0-encodingoroptions-any-promisestring):

```
// We'll call this function multiple times to read the file in chunks.
// Feel free to append additional error handling and logging to this function.
const readChunk = (file, length, position) => {
  return RNFS.read(file, length, position, 'utf8');
}

// Set the number of character to read in each chunk
const length = 4094;
let chunk = '';
let total = '';

// Add together the chunks as you read them.
// When the next chunk is empty, you've reached the end of the file.
do {
  chunk = await readChunk(p, length, total.length);
  total += chunk;
} while (chunk.length > 0);
```